Rendering Jupter Notebook Issue
I am using nbconvert to render out a jupyter notebook and want to try and show case an interactive dataframe so that other members of my team can look at the data, but there are more markdown cells and plots that come after this. However for some reason after I use a
show(df)

in a cell it causes the following problem.
Problem image:
Stuff after the interactive dataframe is outside margins
Note that I am able to use show(df) by:
from itables import init_notebook_mode, show
init_notebook_mode(all_interactive=False)

I do not know if I need to edit the template for fixing this. I have edited the built-in html template named classic to not show any of the code since this is a report kind of document that is being shown to non technical people, and the code does not need to be shown.
To do this this was added to the index.html.j2 file:
{% block input_group -%}
{% endblock input_group %}

{% block in_prompt -%}
{%- endblock in_prompt %}

{% block empty_in_prompt -%}
{%- endblock empty_in_prompt %}

{% block output_prompt %}
{% endblock output_prompt %}

{% block input %}
{%- endblock input %}

{% block output_area_prompt %}
{% endblock output_area_prompt %}

the actual command line prompt to run the conversion is:
jupyter nbconvert --to html "$notebook" --template=classicNoCode --execute

The output I wanted:
I wanted the rest of the rendered outputs of markdown and plots to continue being in the margins of the html page
